# JavaScript for child items in menu in telerik MVC controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I know I can use `.ClientEvents` for the parent items in menu to call JavaScript functions.

Is there a way I can call JavaScript functions from my child menu items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client events for child items as well. Check the [client-side events online demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/menu/clientsideevents) for further details.